# What is the function of the the double parentNode in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, removechild, parent-node

i wanna ask what does this function do and what does the "element.parentNode.parentNode" mean?

```
function removeToDo(element){
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode)
 }
```

Comment: It just removes the parent Node of current element

Comment: Documentation: [`parentNode`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), [`removeChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild), [property access](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: See [How to remove the parent element using plain Javascript](/q/2727717/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

element.parentNode => parentNode 2
element.parentNode.parentNode => parentNode 1

element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild => [parentNode 1].renoveChild //pseudo code

element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode) => [parentNode 1].renoveChild([parentNode 2]) //pseudo code

So parentNode 2 will be removed along with all it's children

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the example below there is a `div` of class `grandparent` which is parent most and it has 2 children `div` and `section` which is a child of `grandparent`.

But when you consider `button` of class `child` which is a child of `parent` and `grandchild` of `grandparent`.

So if you gonna remove the `parent` after chicking the button `child` then you have to go to its parent then tell him to delete his child.

e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);

So this is what this instructs, as you are on `child` then you have to go to its parent of parent i.e `grandparent` to remove the child `parent`.

**If you remove a node then all of its children will also get removed.**

> When you click a button you will get the event object not the node, so you have to select the node from `e.target` then `e.target.parentNode` to get the parent node.

```js
const grandparent = document.querySelector(".grandparent");
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
const child = document.querySelector(".child");

child.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}

.grandparent {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

.parent {
  background-color: rgb(245, 70, 17);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgb(41, 232, 190);
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent container">
  <div class="info">Grandparent </div>
  <section class="parent container">
    <div class="info">Element to be removed </div>
    <button class="child"> click to remove parent  </button>
  </section>
</div>
```